# can cryptocoins be put to good use? now or in the future?

Tags: currencies

it would be amazing is there was a Cryptocoin that could be put to good use.
Like some sort of protein folding.
Curecoin, CureCancerCoin exists but it doesn't put anything towards computational research projects.
Folding@Home is an example of something that could be integrated to a cryptocoin.

Is there anything other than Curecoin or CCC?

Answer (score 0):

[Primecoin](http://primecoin.org/) is an example of a well-known cryptocurrency that is doing something useful. As its name implies, its utility relates to [prime number discovery](https://github.com/primecoin/primecoin/wiki/FAQ#wiki-what-are-the-advantages-of-primecoin):

> The innovative prime proof-of-work in Primecoin not only provides security and minting to the network, but also generates a special form of prime number chains of interest to mathematical research. Thus primecoin network is energy-multiuse, compared to bitcoin network.